# How to prevent multiple instances of Windows 10 XAML applications?

Tags: xaml, windows-10

I'm working on a Windows 10 app. One of the new features of Windows 10 apps is the ability of multiple instances (windows) of the same app. I want to disable this. Has anyone found documentation regarding this scenario?

Comment: DId you check your project properties? Most of the time I found that setting digging around through the properties.

Comment: Yes, I did and see nothing wrt this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can override method OnLaunch in App.xaml.cs :

```
   protected async override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PreviousExecutionState != ApplicationExecutionState.Running) //Check if is there any instance of the App is already running
        {
            base.OnLaunched(e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this Instancing property in manifest file.

[Instancing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211445.aspx)

Comment: Forgot to mention this is a UAP app.